# Let $F$ be a field and $E$ a split field of irred poly $f(x)\in F[x]$. Show that if $c,d\in F$ and $c\neq 0$ then poly $f(cx+d)$ splits in $E[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Let $F$ be a field and $E$ a splitting field of irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$.  Show that if $c,d\in F$ and $c\neq 0$ then the polynomial $f(cx+d)$ splits in $E[x]$.

Let $E$ be a splitting field of $f$.  If $a_1,\dots a_n$ are the roots of $f$ then $E=F(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.  So I was to try and write the roots of $f(cx+d)$, $b_i$, as something that I can say are in $E$, but I am not sure how to progress.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Hint: You don’t need the irreducible part - this is true for all polynomials rhat split in any field. It doesn’t even need to be a splitting field (smallest field where $f$ splits.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so the roots would be $b_i=\frac{a_i-d}{c}\in E$, so $f(cx+d)$ splits over $E$, right?

Comment: Also, note that there can be repeated roots to irreducible polynomials. For example, In $F=\mathbb F_p(z^p)$ and $E=\mathbb F_p(z).$. Then $f(x)=x^p-z^p$ is irreducible in $F[x],$ but splits as $(x-z)^p$ in $E[x].$ So really, the best thing to do is write $f$ as a constant times a product of linear factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h\in E[x]$ is a polynomial, then the map $\nu_h:E[x]\to E[x]$, $\nu_h(g)=g\circ h$ is a ring-homomorphism. Specifically, $$\begin{align}f(cx+d)&=\nu_{cx+d}(f)\\&=LC(f)\prod_{j=1}^n (cx+d-a_j)\\&=c^nLC(f)\prod_{j=1}^n \left(x-\frac{a_j-d}c\right)\end{align}$$